# How can a python code be integrated with Ionic 4

Tags: python, ionic-framework, ionic4

My team is working on Ionic 4 to build an offline mobile app. My task is to work on a python OCR code where an image should be taken as input and text in the image should be sent as output on click of a button in the app.

I've worked on the python code and would like to know how this code can be integrated with the Ionic framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/) rest framework as a backend for your app. But I strongly recommend using AngularJS/NodeJS as your backend service;

Comment: Thank you for the response, but the code has to work offline.